# Contour add to map conditional

Tags: r

I have correlation map then I wan to add contour line on it taking into consideration

(i). for positive correlation enclosed with solid line

(ii). for negative correlation enclosed with dotted line

Here is my scrip just to modify contour line as per mentioned criteria

```
image.plot(lons,lats,cor5FMAM,zlim=c(-0.6,0.6))
contour(lons,lats,cor5FMAM,add=T,at=c(-0.6,0.6,0.2),lwd=0.2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9YiS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would be nice, but I would guess you're looking for

```
contour(lons,lats,cor5FMAM,add=TRUE,at=-0.6,lwd=2,lty=3)
contour(lons,lats,cor5FMAM,add=TRUE,at=c(0.2,0.6,lwd=2,lty=1)
```

?  You could embed this in a looping/`lapply` construct, but it might not be worth it for a one-off plot ...

Comment: Dear Ben! Thank you for an information. I tried to do the following loop but it doesn't work for me. Any help!                                                                                           image.plot(lons,lats,cora1,zlim=c(-0.6,0.6))
map('world2',interior = T,add=TRUE)
n <- 1
for(i in seq(1, length(lons),1)){

    k <- 1
    for(j in seq(1, length(lats),1)){
   if (cora1[i,j]>0.1) 
      {contour(lons,lats,cora1,add=TRUE,lwd=2,lty=3)} 
       else
     {contour(lons,lats,cora1,add=TRUE,lwd=2,lty=1)}
        k <- k + 1
    }
    n <- n + 1
}

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? warning, error, graph doesn't come out as desired?  Can you edit your question above to include this code and make it [reproducible](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) ?

Comment: !! I mean I can't get the graph as I wish. I want the the first condition with contour lty 3and the remain lty 2 but I got the same for all condition                  library(fields)
lats<-seq(0,20,5)
lons<-seq(20,60,5)
a <- array(runif(9*5), c(9,5))

image.plot(lons,lats,a)
map('world2',interior = T,add=TRUE) 
n <- 1 
for(i in seq(1, length(lons),1)){ 
  k <- 1 
  for(j in seq(1, length(lats),1)){ 
    if (a[i,j]>0.6) 
     {contour(lons,lats,a,add=TRUE,lwd=2,lty=3,col='red')}
      else 
   {contour(lons,lats,a,add=TRUE,lwd=2,lty=2,col='blue')}
   k <- k + 1 
  } 
  n <- n + 1 
}